# Custom Grails validation

Tags: validation, grails, grails-domain-class, grails-validation

I would like to check to make sure two fields are not equal and one is greater then the other. Say `yearBorn` and `yearMarried`. They cannot be equal and `yearMarried` must be greater then `yearBorn`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use a 2-parameter custom validator that has access to both the value being validated and the entire instance:

```
static constraints = {
   yearMarried validator: { year, instance ->
      if (year == instance.yearBorn) {
         return 'i18n.code.for.equal.value'
      }
      if (year <= instance.yearBorn) {
         return 'i18n.code.for.born.after.married'
      }
   }
}
```